# How to build a "price-range" display for simple products

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

As far as I can see, there is no way for us to display a price range instead of a static product price for simple products. Ideally we want something like '$1000 - $1250' on the product page and category pages.

I could not find any extensions that will do this, and Magento does not have the out-of-the-box capability.

This may be unsolvable or require more work than we thought, because we will also need the ability to input these prices in the Admin panel somehow.

Comment: What's the setup of your products?  If they have options, or what makes the prices different?

Answer (score 1):

You'll certainly need to build a module for this. The price range will affect everything from the display price, right through to the price the customer pays at checkout. This includes working out tax and shipping.

All this will need to be taken into account.

If you're not using a checkout however, (I can't imagine how you would use a checkout with a price range) then it's fairly trivial to add additional attributes to the product which will give you a min and max price. You can do this with minimal coding and no module creation. [Creating Attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields). You'd only need to code the output of this field to the screen:

```
<?php echo $_product->getMinPrice(); ?>-<?php echo $_product->getMaxPrice(); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

I am trying to figure out the same. using Magento 1.9.1.1.  With Configurable products and simple products.

Where do you place this line of code? What path? Which File?

Comment: Please don't ask a question as an answer. Use the comment.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Trying to figure this out so badly.

Comment: @Dan's method of adding <?php echo $_product->getMinPrice(); ?>-<?php echo $_product->getMaxPrice(); ?> solved the problem. Thank you. Dan